# RegEx.Replace but exclude matches within html tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a helper method called HighlightKeywords, which I use on a Forum when viewing search results, to highlight the keyword(s) within the posts, that the user has searched on.

The problem I have is that, say for example the user searches for the keyword 'hotmail', where the HighlightKeywords method then finds matches of that keyword and wraps it with a span tag specifying a style to apply, it's finding matches within html anchor tags and in some cases image tags. As a result, when I render the highlighted posts to screen, the html tags are broken (due to the span being inserted within them).

Here is my function:

```
public static string HighlightKeywords(this string s, string keywords, string cssClassName)
    {
        if (s == string.Empty || keywords == string.Empty)
        {
            return s;
        }

        string[] sKeywords = keywords.Split(' ');
        foreach (string sKeyword in sKeywords)
        {
            try
            {
                s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\b" + sKeyword + @"\b", string.Format("<span class=\"" + cssClassName + "\">{0}</span>", "$0"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            }
            catch {}
        }
        return s;
    }
```

What would be the best way to prevent this from breaking? Even if I could just simply exclude any matches that occur within anchor tags (whether they be web or email addresses) or image tags?

Comment: You really need to use some kind of HTML parser, examine each element for matches. If the containing element is capable of accepting a style on part of contained text then apply it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can't do that. At least, not in a way that won't break. Regular Expressions are not up to the task of parsing HTML. I am really sorry. You will want to read this rant too: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

So, you will probably need to parse the HTML (I hear the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is good) and then only match inside certain portions of the document - excluding anchor tags etc.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, came up with this work around

```
    public static string HighlightKeyWords(string s, string[] KeyWords)
    {
        if (KeyWords != null && KeyWords.Count() > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            foreach (string word in KeyWords)
            {
                s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, word, string.Format("{0}", "{0}$0{1}"), System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            }
        }

        s = string.Format(s, "<mark class='hightlight_text_colour'>", "</mark>");

        return s;
    }
```

Looks kind of scary, but I delay the adding of the html tags until the regex expression has matched all the keywords, adding in the {0} and {1} place holders for the begging and end html tags, instead of the tags. I then add the html tags in at the end,
using the place holders from inside the loop.

Would still break if the keyword of {0} or {1} is passed in as a keyword though.

Comment: This is an excellent idea.

My issue (which is probably like yours, rather than the original posters), is that my initial text was not html, but some of the keywords I wanted to highlight were matching the HTML added by replacing previous keywords - e.g. if a keyword was 'a', it would match the a in '<span'. By marking the start and end of the highlight sections with non-textual tags, this is avoided, and the real tags can be put in place after going through all keywords.

I ended up using "==<==$0==>==" as my replacement text.

Answer (score 0):

Marcus, resurrecting this question because it had a simple solution that wasn't mentioned. This situation sounds very similar to [Match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3 etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174).

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html, here is a simple way to do it.

Taking `hotmail` as an example to show the technique in its simplest form, here's our simple regex:

```
<a.*?</a>|(hotmail)
```

The left side of the alternation matches complete `<a ... </a>` tags. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures `hotmail` to Group 1, and we know they are the right `hotmail` because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

This program shows how to use the regex (see the results at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/VHQ8p2)):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
class Program
{
static void Main() {
var myRegex = new Regex(@"<a.*?</a>|(hotmail)");
string s1 = @"replace this=> hotmail not that => <a href=""http://hotmail.com"">hotmail</a>";

string replaced = myRegex.Replace(s1, delegate(Match m) {
if (m.Groups[1].Value != "") return "<span something>hotmail</span>";
else return m.Value;
});
Console.WriteLine("\n" + "*** Replacements ***");
Console.WriteLine(replaced);


Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();

} // END Main
} // END Program
```

**Reference**

[How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)